# How can I reduce system call overhead when sending a large number of UDP packets? (both Windows & Linux)

Tags: linux, windows, sockets, udp

For example, I am sending 100000 UDP packets on Windows. For each packet, I need to call `WSASendTo()` once, so probably a lot of system call overhead is introduced. Is there a way to do bulk sending and reduce this overhead? I could not find a solution for Windows after googling for a while. Also, I would like to know if this is possible on Linux. Thanks.

Comment: OK. On Linux, I can use `sendmmsg()`. Then this question is for Windows only.

Comment: `WSASendMsg()` seems to be the Windows equivalent of `sendmmsg()`, but the [MSDN document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741693(v=vs.85).aspx) does not explicitly say that this function sends different buffers as different packets.

Comment: No, it isn't an equivalent to `sendmmsg` (nor does `WSARecvFrom` work that way). You can provide more than one buffer and use scatter/gather, yes. But you only have one single value for bytes to send/receive and one single return value for bytes received/sent. This works for a single TCP stream, but not for UDP datagrams where you need N sizes to send and N sizes sent (or success/fail) for N datagrams. To my knowledge, Windows doesn't have any such functionality for sockets.

Comment: Yeah... I did not notice this...

Comment: In addition to sendmmsg, on Linux you could use [netmap](http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/netmap/), which allows you to send (the max on 10GbE) [14.88Mpps using a single core](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/atc12/atc12-final186.pdf) at 900MHz already, i.e. you'll even have head some room on that core.

Comment: @EugeneBeresovsky thanks for the link to netmap, that looks great for one of my projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows you can use the new Windows Registered I/O API (RIO) on Server 2012 and Windows 8 and later.

I've written quite a lot about it [here](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2011/10/windows-8-registered-io-networking-extensions.html) and have done several performance comparisons with the previous APIs that are available on Windows. The performance tests can be found [here](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2012/03/windows-8-registered-io-example-udp-servers.html).

In summary: *"The Registered I/O Networking Extensions, RIO, is a new API that has been added to Winsock to support high-speed networking for increased networking performance with lower latency and jitter. These extensions are targeted primarily for server applications and use pre-registered data buffers and completion queues to increase performance. The increased performance comes from avoiding the need to lock memory pages and copy `OVERLAPPED` structures into kernel space when individual requests are issued, instead relying on pre-locked buffers, fixed sized completion queues, optional event notification on completions and the ability to return multiple completions from kernel space to user space in one go."*

The results of my performance tests seem to imply that it works.

Comment: Excellent tutorial on RIO!

Comment: Wait. The `DataBufferCount` parameter of `RIOSend()` currently can only be 1 or 0, so my problem is still not solved :/ Hope MS will allow us to specify ture `DataBufferCount` in future Windows versions.

Comment: Oh. Maybe I can call `RIOSend()` with `RIO_MSG_DEFER` to push send requests into queue and eventually specify `RIO_MSG_COMMIT_ONLY` to do the actual work. Need benchmarking to see whether this is actually faster..

Comment: Great writeup on RIO and with some data too! Thanks.

Comment: @chen Did you solved DataBufferCount 1 or 0 problem solved ? I have same problem now. It only send 1 packets..

Answer (score 1):

Use `TransmitPackets()` in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has just recently adopted the QUIC protocol. To that end Microsoft had to improve the performance of UDP in Windows.
Therefore we now have a new "UDP send segmentation" and "UDP receive coalescing" API in Windows.

This solves the call overhead problem and takes advantage of hardware offloading on NICs which support it. This is the fastest possible method of transmitting UDP today. But with the caveat that it mostly requires all UDP packets in a call to have the same size.

Read more about it here:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/networking-blog/making-msquic-blazing-fast/ba-p/2268963