# udp performance issue with 10Gbit fiber connection

Tags: networking, network-programming, udp

I have a client application which is very simple.  It only sends udp packets as
fast as possible.

The code is very simple: I state what is the size of every packet (in bytes),
the remote address and the number of ports.
I then open a thread for each port and send packets as fast as possible.

Now the problem is when I run the app on a 10Gbit fiber connection with:
packet_size = 1400
I can only utilize ~25% of the NIC bandwidth (and also CPU is quite high).

When I run the program with:
packet_size = 50000
I manage to utilize ~97% of the NIC bandwidth (and the CPU is lower than 10%).

My explaination for this is the number of syscalls involved in smaller packets.
Imagine each time I send a packet with size of 1500 bytes I call the OS.
The problem is that I want to avoid IP Fragmentation and still be able to utilize
the full potential of the NIC. Any idea how can I achieve that?

BTW: I used both GO and c# to write the mentioned app (both show similar results
with GO being a little more efficient) and I am running on Windows servers 2008.

Comment: How do you measure the NIC bandwidth utilization? Is the bandwidth 10Gbps from NIC to NIC? Is the utilization compounded got all threads? How many threads do you run? Are you only sending the packets in an infinite loop without any pausing? You don't receive anything?

Comment: 1. Task Manager.
 2.Yes
 3. yes 
4.around20
 5. YES. The NIC should be my bottleneck
 6. NO, no data is been received it's just a simple app that sends as many packects as possible. the goal is to see that i can fully utilize the NIC

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I reduce system call overhead when sending a large number of UDP packets? (both Windows & Linux)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20119419/how-can-i-reduce-system-call-overhead-when-sending-a-large-number-of-udp-packets)